# Processing groups of HTML elements using jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML 5 page with several articles.  Each article has a custom attribute titled "MyAttribute":

```
<html>
    <article MyAttribute="x">
    <article MyAttribute="y">
    <article MyAttribute="z">
</html>
```

I would like to create a function that does something like the following pseudo-code:

```
for each article {
    get MyAttribute from the article
    if MyAttribute == x {do this}
    if MyAttribute == y {do that}
    if MyAttribute == z {do something else}
}
```

What is the most efficient way to do this using jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: 1) `<article>`s don't go into `<html>` directly, but rather into e.g. the body. 2) `MyAttribute` is not a valid attribute name.

Comment: Regarding #1, it was just the example I used.  The actual code is inside the body.  Regarding #2, I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using custom attributes, I'd recommend placing your "MyAttribute" in a data-* attribute like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <article data-myattribute="x"></article>
    <article data-myattribute="y"></article>
    <article data-myattribute="z"></article>
  </body>
</html>
```

This creates "more valid" HTML. Then you would write javascript like this:

```
$('article').each(function (){
    switch ($(this).data('myattribute')){
        case 'x':
            //do something for x
            alert('this is case X');
            break;
        case 'y':
            //do something for y
            alert('this is case Y');
            break;
        case 'z':
            //do something for z
            alert('this is case Z');
            break;
    }
 });
```

I've also created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pqny2/3/) of the result for you.

Comment: Is the "data-" prefix a best practice on naming custom attributes, or can you use anything, as long as it is unique?

Comment: Data-* is a special convention. You should not put custom attributes in your markup unless they begin with Data-

Answer (score 1):

```
$('article').each(function() {
    if (this.MyAttribute == 'x')
        //...
    else if (this.MyAttribute == 'y')
        //...
    else if (this.MyAttribute == 'z')
        //...
    //etc.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

f you insert these attributes server-side, the page will not validate
and might trigger quirks mode in the browser.

You could do data-myattribute and then use data().

```
$('article').each(function() {

    var MyAttribute = $(this).attr('data-myattribute');

    if (MyAttribute == 'x')
        //code
    else if (MyAttribute == 'y')
        //code
    else if (MyAttribute == 'z')
        //code
});
```